# Python 2.7.1 SUVAT algorithm not returning values

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm making a program which takes inputs for the properties of a moving particle, returns the remaining properties, and draws a graph of the particle's motion. I've got a section which calculates the remaining inputs which the user didn't enter - it checks which ones are missing, and calculates them depending on which other ones are present. I've set it to print its results in the Python Shell. The section in question is below, and beneath it is the whole program.

```
else:
    #while S == -1 and U == -1 and V == -1 and A == -5000 and T == -1:
    if S == -1:
        if U != -1 and T != -1 and A != -5000:
            S = (U*T) + (0.5*A*(T*T))
        elif U != -1 and V != -1 and T != -1:
            S = 0.5*(U+V)*T
        elif V != -1 and T != -1 and A != -5000:
            S = (V*T)-(0.5*A*(T*T))
        elif V != -1 and U != -1 and A != -5000:
            S = ((V*V)-(T*T))/(2*A)
        print "S %d" % S

    if U == -1:
        if V != -1 and A != -5000 and T != -1:
            U = V - (A*T)
        elif S != -1 and A != -5000 and T != -1:
            U = S - ((0.5*A*(T*T)))/T
        elif S != -1 and V != -1 and T != -1:
            U = ((2*S)/T) - V
        elif V != -1 and A != -5000 and S != -1:
            U = sqrt((T*T)-(2*A*S))
        print "U %d" % U

    if V == -1:
        if U != -1 and A != -5000 and T != -1:
            V = U + (A*T)
        elif S != -1 and U != -1 and T != -1:
            V = ((2*S)/T) - U
        elif S != -1 and U != -1 and A != -5000:
            V = sqrt((U*U)+(2*A*S))
        elif S != -1 and T != -1 and A != -5000:
            V = (S + (0.5*A*(T*T)))/T
        print "V %d" % V

    if A == -5000:
        if V != -1 and U != -1 and T != -1:
            A = (V-U)/T
        elif S != -1 and T != -1 and U != -1:
            A = (S-(U*T))/((T*T)*2)
        elif V != -1 and U != -1 and S != -1:
            A = (((V*V)-(U*U))/S)/2
        elif S != -1 and V != -1 and T != -1:
            A = ((((V*T) - S)*2)/(T*T))
        print "A %d" % A

    if T == -1:
        if V != -1 and U != -1 and A != -5000:
            T = (V-U)/A
        elif S != -1 and U != -1 and A != -5000:
            T = sqrt(((S-(U*T))*2)/A)
        elif S != -1 and U != -1 and V != -1:
            T = S/(0.5*(U+V))
        elif S != -1 and V != -1 and A != -5000:
            T = (-V + (sqrt((-(V*V)-(4*(0.5*A)*S)))))
            if T < 0:
                T = (-V - (sqrt((-(V*V)-(4*(0.5*A)*S)))))
                if T < 0:
                    T = (-V + (sqrt((-(V*V)-(4*(0.5*A)*S)))))
        print "T %d" % T

    #if S != -1 and U != -1 and V != -1 and A != -5000 and T != -1:
    #break

    sang = int(sin(Ang))
    s2ang = int(sin(2*Ang))

    MX = ((U*U)*(s2ang))/(-9.81)
    print "MX %d" % MX

    MY = ((U*U)*(sang^2))/(-19.62)
    print "MY %d" % MY

    HU = U*(cos(Ang))

    VU = U*(sin(Ang))

    endx = MX*2

    x = (0, MX, endx)

    y = (0, MY, 0)

    entries = 0

    a.plot(x,y)
    canvas.show()
```

**Whole Program:**

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from decimal import *
from math import sqrt, sin, cos
from tkMessageBo

x import askokcancel, showerror
global S, U, V, A, T, Ang
global inStr, i, acttyp
S=-1
U=-1
V=-1
A=-5000
T=-1
Ang=-1
SEntry = False
UEntry = False
VEntry = False
AEntry = False
TEntry = False

class MainMenu(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("MechSim 0.4")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("clam")

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        StartButton = Button(self, text="New Simulation", command=create_window).place(x=50, y=60)
        ExampleButton = Button(self, text="Example Simulation", command=create_window).place(x=50, y=110)
        ExitButton = Button(self, text="Exit MechSim", command=self.end).place(x=50, y=160)
        Title = Label(self, text="MechSim 0.4", foreground="blue", font=("helvetica", 20)).place(x=300, y=50)

    def end(self):
        ans = askokcancel('Really quit?', "Really quit?")
        if ans: quit()

def create_window():
    global canvas, a
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from numpy import arange, sin, pi
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
    from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler

    mainwind = Toplevel()
    mainwind.geometry("800x500+300+300")
    mainwind.wm_title("MechSim Simulator")
    mainwind.wm_style = Style()
    mainwind.wm_style.theme_use("clam")
    Title = Label(mainwind, text="MechSim 0.4", foreground="blue", font=("helvetica", 20)).place(x=620, y=7)

    f = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
    s = sin(2*pi*t)

    a.plot(t,s)
    a.set_xlabel('Horizontal Distance (Metres)')
    a.set_ylabel('Vertical Distance (Metres)')

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    #ax.set_xlim(0,1000)
    #ax.set_ylim(0,1000)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=mainwind)
    canvas.show()

    canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=270, y=50)
    f.subplots_adjust(left=0.16, bottom=0.14)

    NewPartButton = Button(mainwind, text ="Add New Particle", command=AddNewPart).place(x=50,y=50)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,mainwind)
    toolbar.update()

def testVal(inStr,i,acttyp):
    ind=int(i)
    if acttyp == '1': #insert
        if not inStr[ind].isdigit():
            return False
    return True

def AddNewPart():
    global SInp, UInp, VInp, AInp, TInp, AngInp
    NewPartWind=Toplevel()
    NewPartWind.geometry("400x250+300+300")
    NewPartWind.wm_title("New Particle")
    NewPartWind.wm_style = Style()
    NewPartWind.wm_style.theme_use("clam")

    SLab=Label(NewPartWind, text="Distance Travelled (S)", foreground="blue", font=("helvetica", 8)).place(x=10,y=30)
    ULab=Label(NewPartWind, text="Initial Velocity (U)", foreground="blue", font=("helvetica", 8)).place(x=10,y=60)
    VLab=Label(NewPartWind, text="Final Velocity (V)", foreground="blue", font=("helvetica", 8)).place(x=10,y=90)
    ALab=Label(NewPartWind, text="Acceleration (A)", foreground="blue", font=("helvetica", 8)).place(x=10,y=120)
    TLab=Label(NewPartWind, text="Time Taken (T)", foreground="blue", font=("helvetica", 8)).place(x=10,y=150)
    AngLab=Label(NewPartWind, text="Initial Angle", foreground="blue", font=("helvetica", 8)).place(x=10,y=180)

    SInp=Entry(NewPartWind, validate="key")
    SInp['validatecommand'] = (SInp.register(testVal),'%P','%i','%d')
    SInp.place(x=140,y=30)

    UInp=Entry(NewPartWind, validate="key")
    UInp['validatecommand'] = (UInp.register(testVal),'%P','%i','%d')
    UInp.place(x=140,y=60)

    VInp=Entry(NewPartWind, validate="key")
    VInp['validatecommand'] = (VInp.register(testVal),'%P','%i','%d')
    VInp.place(x=140,y=90)

    AInp=Entry(NewPartWind, validate="key")
    AInp.place(x=140,y=120)

    TInp=Entry(NewPartWind, validate="key")
    TInp['validatecommand'] = (TInp.register(testVal),'%P','%i','%d')
    TInp.place(x=140,y=150)

    AngInp=Entry(NewPartWind, validate="key")
    AngInp['validatecommand'] = (AngInp.register(testVal),'%P','%i','%d')
    AngInp.place(x=140,y=180)

    SOk = Button(NewPartWind, text="Ok", command=recS).place(x=290, y=25)

    UOk = Button(NewPartWind, text="Ok", command=recU).place(x=290, y=55)

    VOk = Button(NewPartWind, text="Ok", command=recV).place(x=290, y=85)

    AOk = Button(NewPartWind, text="Ok", command=recA).place(x=290, y=115)

    TOk = Button(NewPartWind, text="Ok", command=recT).place(x=290, y=145)

    AngOk = Button(NewPartWind, text="Ok", command=recAng).place(x=290, y=175)

    SimOk = Button(NewPartWind, text="Simulate Particle", command=CalcPart).place(x=10, y=210)


def recS():
    global SEntry
    SEntry = False
    Stest = int(SInp.get())
    if Stest != -1 and Stest <= 1000 and Stest >= 1:
        S=Stest
        print S
        SEntry = True
    else:
        errorbox = showerror("Error", "Please enter an integer between 1 and 1000")

def recU():
    global UEntry
    UEntry = False
    Utest = int(UInp.get())
    if Utest != -1 and Utest <= 1000:
        U=Utest
        print U
        UEntry = True
    else:
        errorbox = showerror("Error", "Please enter an integer between 0 and 1000")

def recV():
    global VEntry
    VEntry = False
    Vtest = int(VInp.get())
    if Vtest != -1 and Vtest <= 1000:
        V=Vtest
        print V
        VEntry = True
    else:
        errorbox = showerror("Error", "Please enter an integer between 0 and 1000")

def recA():
    global AEntry
    AEntry = False
    try:
        Atest = int(AInp.get())
    except ValueError:
        errorbox = showerror("Error", "Please enter a number between -1000 and 1000")
    else:
        if Atest > -1000 and Atest < 1000:
            A=Atest
            print A
            AEntry = True
        else:
            errorbox = showerror("Error", "Please enter a number between -1000 and 1000")

def recT():
    global TEntry
    TEntry = False
    Ttest = int(TInp.get())
    if Ttest != 0 and Ttest != -1 and Ttest <= 1000:
        T=Ttest
        print T
        TEntry = True
    else:
        errorbox = showerror("Error", "Please enter an integer between 1 and 1000")

def recAng():
    Angtest = int(AngInp.get())
    if Angtest <= 90 and Angtest >= 1:
        Ang=Angtest
        print Ang
    else:
        errorbox = showerror("Error", "Please enter an integer between 1 and 90")

def CalcPart():
    MX = 0
    MY = 0
    global SEntry, UEntry, VEntry, AEntry, TEntry, S, U, V, A, T, Ang
    entries = 0
    if SEntry == True:
        entries += 1
    if UEntry == True:
        entries += 1
    if VEntry == True:
        entries += 1
    if AEntry == True:
        entries += 1
    if TEntry == True:
        entries += 1

    if entries < 3 and Ang == -1:
        entries = 0
        errorbox = showerror("Error", "Please enter 4 values including an angle of trajectory.")
    else:
        #while S == -1 and U == -1 and V == -1 and A == -5000 and T == -1:
        if S == -1:
            if U != -1 and T != -1 and A != -5000:
                S = (U*T) + (0.5*A*(T*T))
            elif U != -1 and V != -1 and T != -1:
                S = 0.5*(U+V)*T
            elif V != -1 and T != -1 and A != -5000:
                S = (V*T)-(0.5*A*(T*T))
            elif V != -1 and U != -1 and A != -5000:
                S = ((V*V)-(T*T))/(2*A)
            print "S %d" % S

        if U == -1:
            if V != -1 and A != -5000 and T != -1:
                U = V - (A*T)
            elif S != -1 and A != -5000 and T != -1:
                U = S - ((0.5*A*(T*T)))/T
            elif S != -1 and V != -1 and T != -1:
                U = ((2*S)/T) - V
            elif V != -1 and A != -5000 and S != -1:
                U = sqrt((T*T)-(2*A*S))
            print "U %d" % U

        if V == -1:
            if U != -1 and A != -5000 and T != -1:
                V = U + (A*T)
            elif S != -1 and U != -1 and T != -1:
                V = ((2*S)/T) - U
            elif S != -1 and U != -1 and A != -5000:
                V = sqrt((U*U)+(2*A*S))
            elif S != -1 and T != -1 and A != -5000:
                V = (S + (0.5*A*(T*T)))/T
            print "V %d" % V

        if A == -5000:
            if V != -1 and U != -1 and T != -1:
                A = (V-U)/T
            elif S != -1 and T != -1 and U != -1:
                A = (S-(U*T))/((T*T)*2)
            elif V != -1 and U != -1 and S != -1:
                A = (((V*V)-(U*U))/S)/2
            elif S != -1 and V != -1 and T != -1:
                A = ((((V*T) - S)*2)/(T*T))
            print "A %d" % A

        if T == -1:
            if V != -1 and U != -1 and A != -5000:
                T = (V-U)/A
            elif S != -1 and U != -1 and A != -5000:
                T = sqrt(((S-(U*T))*2)/A)
            elif S != -1 and U != -1 and V != -1:
                T = S/(0.5*(U+V))
            elif S != -1 and V != -1 and A != -5000:
                T = (-V + (sqrt((-(V*V)-(4*(0.5*A)*S)))))
                if T < 0:
                    T = (-V - (sqrt((-(V*V)-(4*(0.5*A)*S)))))
                    if T < 0:
                        T = (-V + (sqrt((-(V*V)-(4*(0.5*A)*S)))))
            print "T %d" % T

        #if S != -1 and U != -1 and V != -1 and A != -5000 and T != -1:
        #break

        sang = int(sin(Ang))
        s2ang = int(sin(2*Ang))

        MX = ((U*U)*(s2ang))/(-9.81)
        print "MX %d" % MX

        MY = ((U*U)*(sang^2))/(-19.62)
        print "MY %d" % MY

        HU = U*(cos(Ang))

        VU = U*(sin(Ang))

        endx = MX*2

        x = (0, MX, endx)

        y = (0, MY, 0)

        entries = 0

        a.plot(x,y)
        canvas.show()


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x300+300+300")
    app = MainMenu(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Please, extend the question with more details.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that the above algorithm isn't assigning values for S, U, V, A and T.